# Conexión Postman con Lambda AWS

Tags: java, aws, postman, lambda, gateway

Dentro de AWS, en la sección "Probar" que ofrece Lambda, chequeo el método POST y GET que fueron asociados a una Api Gateway, funciona correctamente al enviar un JSON (veo la respuesta con los valores que establecí en las claves).

Pero en POSTMAN, copio la URL que me da API Getaway, selecciono el método POST y GET y como respuesta veo esto:

```
{
    "response": "Bienvenido null null, para terminar tu logueo, por favor, verifica tu email: null"
}
```

No se están tomando los valores que establecí en la solicitud:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "lastName": "api",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: Sin código no podemos ayudarte.